# Network Timeout for Containerized Service in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-container-service

We lift and shifted our cloud services to Azure Service Fabric. We converted our services to Windows Container and successfully deployed to the cluster. However, we're getting a lot of timeout issue while uploading file to Sharepoint and accessing Azure SQL Server.

See the example below:

SQL: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)

Sharepoint: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

Note: These issues are not happening is cloud services.